# Distribution of W given that it consists of linear combinations of a normal random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ where $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Let $Y = BX + c$ and Z = $DX + e$ where $B$ is an $n \times k $ matrix and $c$ is an $n$ vector of constants. $D$ is an $m \times k$ matrix of constants and $e$ is an $m$ vector of constants. Let $W = (Y Z)'$. What is the distribution of $W$?

I am trying to write W as a linear combination of $X$ but failed to find a way to do so. My guess is that $W$ is normal.

Comment: Do you mean $W=(Y,Z)'$?

Comment: Yes. $W$ is a vector comprising of $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: Of course $W$ is normal, since $W=(B,D)X+(c,e)$ where $X$ is normal.

Comment: what's the variance of W then? [B, D] Var (X) [B, D]'?